# Suggestion to add synonym for tag [servicemix]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

In general all tags related to an apache project are prefixed by `apache-` (e.g [apache-karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-karaf), [apache-camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-camel), etc...).

I do not know what is the best option:

1. Rename the existing tag [servicemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicemix) to [apache-servicemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-servicemix)
2. Create a tag synonym [apache-servicemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-servicemix) for [servicemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicemix)

For the 1st option, is there any other way than just editing all question and retag with the new tag (if my request is accepted)?